# DefaultHttpClient causing delay in async task

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat, http-get

I am developing an app which send request to server using **DefaultHttpClient**.I am sending request with GET method.if the port number is wrong then i get connection timeout exception.I have used handler for the exception & return a value when exception occurs. But the sad part is **Post Execute** is called after 60 seconds.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... url) 
    {

        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        HttpGet httpGet = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient=null;

        try 
          { 
            httpGet = new HttpGet(url[0]);
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 5000;
            int sockettimeout=5000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, sockettimeout);
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);               
             HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet );
             int code=httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
}
catch (IOException e)
          {

             if(e.toString().contains("org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException"))
             {
                 Log.i("RAE", "Connection Timeedout");
                 httpClient.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();
                 httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

                 httpGet.abort();



                     Log.i("log", "Before  Return");
                    return "done";
             }
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
             Log.i("log", "Async finished");


}
```

But post is called after 60 seconds.May i know why it is happening

Comment: You need to post more code. It's likely that the server is waiting 60 secs to timeout before returning a timeout error. That is not a client side issue... or post logcat so that it is more clear what your problem is.

Comment: i get exception as 
12-31 13:20:04.346: IAGS(6537): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /timed out

Comment: that's one line from your logcat, more lines would be helpful. Also, you should add something like "e.toString()" to give you more info... not just "e.toString().contains()" - just show it all, right???

Comment: e.toString has given this info

Comment: print out what `url[0]` contains, are you sure it's a valid and accessible URL?

Comment: url is correct but port number is not correct so server throw timeout exception

Comment: yes http://192.168.1.42/path/AndroidLogin